# I need a clarification on the word "structure" please?

Tags: meaning

Structure means the way something is built or arranged. So we know that built means construct (something) by putting parts or material together.
if it's the way of something built doesn't that mean you can ask "What is the structure of this dish?" to know how it was made? instead of asking "How did you make this dish?". Please tell me if something is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have the definition of structure a bit wrong.

[*Structure*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/structure) means the order of objects or people, or the way something is formed from individual parts. You have organizational structures in companies or molecular structures in biology.
If you use *structure* for a building, you indirectly refer to the elements that make up the building.

If you take that term over to the culinary world, yes, you can indeed ask "What's the structure of your dish?", but you wouldn't be asking about the way your friend cooked some food, but about the artistic concept or the ideas behind it. So in short, nothing an everyday cook would even think about, let alone could answer. Should you ever have the chance to chat with a Michelin star chef, he or she on the other hand could answer that question with details on flavour, textures, colour etc.

For every other case, stick to a variety of "How do you make this?" or "What do you put into the dish?".